# apt-get update problem when updating a reprepro repository

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, repository

i have made a repository using reprepro on my Ubuntu 13.04, i uploaded this repo to sourceforge.net , i can download packages from it and i can update it, put after adding the repository to my software sources and running a sudo apt-get update this error is appeard in terminal:

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sourceforge.net_projects_helal_files_repository_dists_The%5fOld%5fMoon_Release.gpg is not what the server reported 0 353
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sourceforge.net_projects_helal_files_repository_dists_The%5fOld%5fMoon_Release is not what the server reported 0 161
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sourceforge.net_projects_helal_files_repository_dists_The%5fOld%5fMoon_main_binary-i386_Packages is not what the server reported 0 387
```

as i said, i can download and upload packages even that, but this message is very noisy, i know that there is a way to ignore those message from apt-get but i need a solution for a user that runs sudo apt-get update only with no other tweaks for his own apt-get.

is there a fix for that?
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use http instead of https.
Apt has some strange problems with https repositories.
Seems like nobody wants to fix it.

Comment: I use only http, still the same